# How to resolve permission denied maybe missing internet permission?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am using Netbeans7.2 and entered uses-permission also but i have this error Java.net.Socket Exception Internet denied(Maybe missing internet permission )`
my AndroidManifest file like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="importacao.dados"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
        <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <activity android:name="importacao"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

//Button

```
cliente.setOnClickListener(new  Button.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        InputStream is = null;
         ArrayList namevaluePairs = new ArrayList();
        List r = new ArrayList();
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost;
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/cliente.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluePairs));
        HttpResponse response;
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;
      while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
     {
      //   
     }}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       Log.e("Erro",e.toString());
    }}});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your uses-permission tag to be outside the application tag.  You also might need to add a uses-permission for android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, not sure how netbeans works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="importacao.dados"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: thanks my problem solved to doing this , sir i have another question my namevaluePairs showing me 0 items thats means do not populating data from Mysql db ? here is my php file code

Comment: <?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","abc");
mysql_select_db("fabricacao");
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM cliente") ;
$nome ='nome';
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$output[]=$rows;
print(json_encode($output));
}
?>

Comment: It's best to post a new question for that, keeps things clean.

Comment: Hi Ralgha! I have the same problem but my permission is in right place outside application tag, secondly i have added access_network_permission_state too.
Any Help will be regarded