# Permission denied maybe missing internet permission. Force close error on adding ad network

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions

I have seen many question regarding this issue on stack overflow.I have same problem like this question below but with a slight change in situation.
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922365/how-to-resolve-permission-denied-maybe-missing-internet-permission)!
Firstly I am using Eclipse.
Secondly I have the permissions in right place that is "Outside the application Tag."I have permissions for internet and for access_network_state as well.
I do not know where the problem is. Your help will be regarded.
Here is my Manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.test.GamePlayActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>


    <!-- Heyzap Ads Start  -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <receiver android:name="com.heyzap.sdk.ads.PackageAddedReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="package" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Heyzap Ads Ends   -->



</application>
```

Here is the Log of this Application

`05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8341
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10098 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:680)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:476)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.internal.Connectivity.connectionType(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.sdk.ads.FetchRequest.getParams(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.sdk.ads.FetchManager.fetch(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.sdk.ads.InterstitialAd.fetch(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.sdk.ads.InterstitialAd.fetch(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at com.heyzap.sdk.ads.HeyzapAds$1.run(Unknown Source)
05-10 12:20:40.058: E/AndroidRuntime(8535):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)`

Comment: Post your manifest and logcat please

Comment: I am sorry it is not available right now but will do it ASAP.
But the question in the link has the same manifest i believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved the issue but could not get the valid reason and valid solution of the problem.
I just added the access_network_state permission twice in the manifest.Now my manifest permissions looks like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

This worked for me.